# Spray custom status message

Tags: spray

I'd like to respond with `404 Somethingdifferenthere`, instead of just `404 Not Found`. The `StatusCode` class is sealed so I can't just make up my own. I don't want to override the message for all 404s either, just in one specific case. Is that possible?

Comment: What do you mean specific case? A specific URL, or what would be a condition?

Comment: @lpiepiora anything, literally. like, if (true) { /* respond with "404 Blah" here. */ }

Comment: I have added a solution to your problem, @YuriUshakov. Would you care to accept it?

Answer (score 1):

To use this you have to register the custom code first:

```scala
val My404 = StatusCodes.registerCustom(404, "Somethingdifferenthere")
```

..and then use it like this:

```scala
val aRoute = path("notexisting") {
  get {
    complete(My404)
  }
}
```

See [this PR to Spray](https://github.com/spray/spray/issues/564) and [its commit](https://github.com/spray/spray/commit/a9e0d2c963ccf31a839636717453a83667321910), especially the tests code for reference and other examples.

Also note that it's possible to create custom status messages ONLY for existing numeric status codes. So you can register and then return `HTTP/1.1 404 Somethingdifferenthere` but NOT `HTTP/1.1 666 Something EVIL happened`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it locally, you can use a simple `complete` directive. For example:

```
val aRoute = path("notexisting") {
  get {
    dynamic {
      if (System.currentTimeMillis() % 2 == 0) complete(StatusCodes.NotFound, "Not Found")
      else complete("OK")
    }
  }
}
```

Note that you have to use a dynamic, if the route must be constructed on each request. You can avoid it if you put it to `complete` directive, like this:

```
val anotherRoute2 = path("notexisting2") {
  get {
    complete {
      if (System.currentTimeMillis() % 2 == 0) HttpResponse(status = StatusCodes.NotFound, entity = "Custom Message")
      else HttpResponse(status = StatusCodes.OK, entity = "All Okay")
    }
  }
}
```

If you want to do it globally you can do it by supplying your own `RejectionHandler`, when executing `runRoute`. It can be passed as an implicit value.

Consider following fragment of code:

```
class MyActor extends akka.actor.Actor with HttpService {

  implicit val rejectionHandler: RejectionHandler = RejectionHandler {
    case Nil => complete(StatusCodes.NotFound, "Something Else Here")
  } orElse RejectionHandler.Default

  def receive = runRoute(myRoute) /*implicit rejection handler is applied here */

  def actorRefFactory = context

  val myRoute = path("existing") {
    get {
      respondWithMediaType(MediaTypes.`text/html`) {
        complete {
          <html>
            <body>
              <h1>OK</h1>
            </body>
          </html>
        }
      }
    }
  }

}
```

The custom `rejectionHandler`will be applied and it will transform standard `NotFound` requests to the ones having text `"Something Else Here"`.

Comment: What you described puts the custom message into response entity. What I'm asking is how to modify the *status message*. In a `HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found` response, I need to change the `Not Found` text piece, akin to `javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse#sendError()`. Calling `sendError(404, "Blah")` would respond with `404 Blah`, not `404 Not Found`.